# How to remove or hide the Subject field for comments?

Tags: 9, comments

I have added a comment field to a content type. It is of the default comment type.

I don't want my commenters to fill in a subject, rather, just a comment body.

Trying to remove the Subject field, I went to `admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/fields` but there I only find `comment_body`, not something like `comment_subject`.

How to remove or hide the Subject field for comments?
In earlier phrasing, how to not require a subject from commenters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the subject, but you can hide it so that it will be auto-generated and not displayed.

Go to Admin -> Structure -> Comment types -> Default Comments -> **Manage Form Display** tab (`/admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/form-display`) and then drag **Subject** to **Disabled**.  Then save.

Note: If you only see the heading "Comments" but no name field and no comment field, and you are not logged in, then you need to give anonymous users permission to post comments.

Comment: On **Manage form display**, you should see **Author** and **Comment** (the comment body), and then below that will be **Disabled** with **Subject**.  This is working in Drupal 9.4.6; I wrote this answer based on a site configured as written.

Comment: Also check your theme.  Some non-standard themes have poor support for comments.