# How to hide the comment subject field?

Tags: 9, comments

In Drupal 7, there used to be a checkbox: "Allow comment title". Unchecking that, and there was no comment title.

I am unable to locate a similar setting in Drupal 9.

I've found: [How to remove or hide the Subject field for comments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/313101/12076)

It explains how to auto-generate the subject field for a comment. This is *not* what I am asking. I don't want to *display* any subject field when showing a comment. If you're familiar with how comments work in issues posted on Drupal.org, that is the solution I am looking for.

**Edit**: In comments, it is suggested that you can do this by navigating to the "Manage display" tab for the comment type. However, this is a screen dump (Drupal 9.4.8) of that tab for the default comment type:

[image: Manage display]

I see no *obvious* way to set the title not to be shown.

Comment: Can't you hide the subject field on the Manage Display tab?

Comment: That's how you do it. Admin -> Structure -> Comment types -> [COMMENT TYPE] -> manage display. Set the title to not be shown.

Comment: @PatrickKenny, no you can't you hide the subject field on the Manage Display tab. See edited question.

Comment: @Jaypan see edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to copy core's [comment.html.twig](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drupal/drupal/9.5.x/core/modules/comment/templates/comment.html.twig) and put it in your theme's /templates folder and remove the [`<h3{{ title_attributes }}>{{ title }}</h3>`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.5.x/core/modules/comment/templates/comment.html.twig#L101) line.

Comment: I agree that this will work, but I really do not want to create a subtheme just to be able to hide the Subject. I would prefer to do this from the administrative GUI. The contributed extension named **Manage display** let me do that, so I've added that as a self-answer.

Answer (score 3):

If one installs the contributed extension named [**Manage display**](https://www.drupal.org/project/manage_display) the "Subject" field becomes exposed under the "Manage display" tab for a comment. You can then move it to the "Disabled" section to hide it.